# Wordpress Custom Meta Boxes Validation

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to validate custom meta box fields without using javascript. If it doesn't validate I want to stop the post from being saved to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the 'save_post' action is run AFTER publishing and updating, there's really no way of validating custom keys without a hackish alternative.

However, I'm thinking you can mimic the functionality you want by employing 'save_post' in the way Viral suggested, but rather than interrupt or cancel the saving process upon a validation error, you can just delete the post altogether:

```
add_action('save_post', 'validate_meta');
function validate_meta($post_id)
{
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return $post_id;
    /*USE THIS ONLY IF YOU ARE UTILIZING NONCE FIELDS IN A CUSTOM META BOX
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['metabox_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) )
      return $post_id;*/
    /*Use plugin_basename(__FILE__) if this is an actual plugin, rather than
    a part of your theme*/

    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
    {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    }

    /*VALIDATE YOUR METADATA HERE HOWEVER YOU LIKE
    if(is_valid($_POST['metadata']))
        $validated = true;
    else
        $validated = false;
    */

    if(!$validated)
        wp_delete_post($post_id, true);
    else
        return $post_id;
}
```

The only thing to watch out for with this approach is that it will run upon both Publishing and Updating as well. You may want to consider adding a check to ensure that the post is deleted only for newly published posts, and updated posts are rolled back to a previous version and the invalid revision is deleted.

Comment: yep this seems like the only available option. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Maybe you should use following hooks: [sanitize_{$type}_meta_{$key}_for_{$subtype}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sanitize_object_type_meta_meta_key_for_object_subtype/), [sanitize_{$type}_meta_{$key}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sanitize_object_type_meta_meta_key/), [auth_{$type}_meta_{$key}_for_{$object_subtype}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_object_type_meta_meta_key_for_object_subtype/), [auth_{$type}_meta_{$key}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_object_type_meta_meta_key/)

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_insert_post_data` filter is what you are looking for. Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_validation_function' );

function my_validation_function( $data ) {
    // Don't want to do this on autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $data;
    if ( $data['some_key'] != 'some_value' ||
         $_POST['some_meta_key'] != 'some_meta_value' ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft'; // or whatever status to revert to
        add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'remove_message'); // remove the publish success message
    }
    return $data;
}

function remove_message( $location ) {
    return remove_query_arg( 'message', $location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the WP Codex @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box, you call the `save_post` hook and specify the function that will be run to validate/save your data:

```
/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata');
```

Then you define that function, which will automatically be passed the post id. Additionally, you can access the $_POST array to get the values in your metaboxes:

```
/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return $post_id;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
      return $post_id;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];

  // Do something with $mydata 
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta(), or 
  // a custom table (see Further Reading section below)

   return $mydata;
}
```

All of your routines to valid data will be done within this function. In the end, you will likely save the data using something like:
`update_post_meta('meta_key', 'meta_value');`

Comment: But this will not prevent the post from being saved in case custom options are not validated properly.